# What is the best way to return different types of ResponseEntity in Spring-Boot (Error Handling for REST with Spring)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, error-handling

I have written simple REST application in `Spring Boot` (`Spring` Framework).

It returns `ResponseEntity<Success>` as **Success** response in the controller level. But I want to return a completely different **Error** response `ResponseEntity<Error>`, if there is an error (*validation error, logic error, runtime error*) in the API.

**Success** & **Error** responses are completely different for the application.
`Success` & `Error` are the 2 java classes which the application uses to represent **Success** & **Error** responses.

What is the best way to return different types of `ResponseEntity` in `Spring-Boot` (Best way to handle the errors for REST with `Spring`)?

Comment: One solution is to use `ResponseEntity<Object>`. An other is to use the a BaseClass or Interface for types Success and Error.

Comment: Could you not just return `ResponseEntity` in yout method definition ? `  public ResponseEntity myControllerMethod(...)    and return either a `ResponseEntity<Success>` or a `ResponseEntity<Error>`

Comment: `ResponseEntity<Either<Error, Success>>` would be good, if you could manage to implement the data structure in java

Answer (score 203, accepted):

I recommend using Spring's `@ControllerAdvice` to handle errors. Read [this guide](https://www.toptal.com/java/spring-boot-rest-api-error-handling) for a good introduction, starting at the section named "Spring Boot Error Handling". For an in-depth discussion, there's [an article](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) in the Spring.io blog that was updated on April, 2018.

A brief summary on how this works:

- Your controller method should only return `ResponseEntity<Success>`. It will not be responsible for returning error or exception responses.
- You will implement a class that handles exceptions for all controllers.  This class will be annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`
- This controller advice class will contain methods annotated with `@ExceptionHandler`
- Each exception handler method will be configured to handle one or more exception types. These methods are where you specify the response type for errors
- For your example, you would declare (in the controller advice class) an exception handler method for the validation error.  The return type would be `ResponseEntity<Error>`

With this approach, you only need to implement your controller exception handling in one place for all endpoints in your API. It also makes it easy for your API to have a uniform exception response structure across all endpoints. This simplifies exception handling for your clients.

Comment: This is the standard and should be the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: This is great advice, and definitely the way in which I would implement error handling if I were coding a project from scratch.

Comment: What about the fact that it is not recommended to handle expected application flow via Exceptions in Java? For example a getCustomerForIBAN returns an Optional exposed via a REST api `GET /api/customer/{iban}` which returns 200 ok or 404 not found? Would you advice to then throw an Exception and handle that the same way?

Comment: If you want to avoid using exceptions in Java, you can design your controller method to return a `ResponseEntity`. `ResponseEntity` allows you to control the HTTP status code that is returned, and it is a generic type so you can return any object structure.  Here's an explanation on how to use it: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity

Comment: As an addendum to my comment: (1) my comment implies that `ResponseEntity` and Java exceptions are mutually exclusive, which is not the case, (2) the OP wanted to return a different type under exception/error conditions, which makes `@ControllerAdvice` a better option, and (3) you can use both `ResponseEntity` and `@ControllerAdvice` for the same method.

Comment: Is this really the standard for handling "validation errors" though? Validation errors are meant to be a controlled flow in your service layer (presumably). Why would we let an Exception bubble up to the Controller level unhandled? I understand unexpected Exceptions (i.e. 5xx error codes) but not validation ones (4xx). Am I missing something?

Comment: This is the standard for handling errors that other layers of the application allow to propagate up or throw explicitly. RE: validation errors, the service layer can still catch and handle. I was too restrictive when I stated "handle validation errors" in the first sentence. I've deleted "validation" to indicate this is for errors in general. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Follow this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117717/what-is-the-best-way-to-return-different-types-of-responseentity-in-spring-mvc-o/63500498#63500498

Comment: if you return > 1 type (here SUCCESS and ERROR), doesn't that mean you cannot type your responseEntity? you have to chk and convert it
    
    instead of ResponseEntity<SUCCESS> res = restTemplate.exchange( url, GET, req, new ParameterizedTypeReference<SUCCESS>);
    
    you have to:
    ResponseEntity<String> res = restTemplate.exchange( url, get, req, String.class to make it easy );
    if ( res.getStatusCode == 200 or 204 )
    String json = res.getBody();
    SUCCESS suc = jsonToObject( json, SUCCESS type ref );
    else
    ERROR err = jsonToObject( json, ERROR type ref );

Answer (score 58):

You can return generic wildcard `<?>` to return `Success` and `Error` on a same request mapping method

```
public ResponseEntity<?> method() {
    boolean b = // some logic
    if (b)
        return new ResponseEntity<Success>(HttpStatus.OK);
    else
        return new ResponseEntity<Error>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT); //appropriate error code
}
```

**@Mark Norman answer is the correct approach**

Comment: Its only the case that code quality tools ( like Sonar Lint ) flag this coding practice with **Generic wildcard types should not be used in return parameters (squid:S1452)**

Comment: This is rather a **hack** how to circumvent the (imperfect) mechanism of Java generics. @MarkNorman's answer is the standard and should be the accepted one.

Comment: I just came across the same problem and I'm looking into creating something that would work with VAVRs `Either`, so that I could have a `public ResponseEntity<Either<Error, Success>> method()` or better a `public Either<ResponseEntity<Error>, ResponseEntity<Success>> method()`. I think the way to do that would be to create a `HttpMessageConverter` that would know how to handle that and would simply convert the Either to the left/right side and let normal processing happen .. that way I could signal my valid states without using exceptions.. any ideas on this one?

Comment: Is there a way to convert wildcard generic to a specific generic?

Answer (score 14):

Using **ResponseStatusException** you can return error message, different HTTP status code, and DTO at the **same time**.

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> saveUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
    if(userDto.getId() != null) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE,"A new user cannot already have an ID");
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.saveUser(userDto));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

i am not sure but, I think you can use `@ResponseEntity` and `@ResponseBody` and send 2 different one is Success and second is error message like :

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/book2", produces =MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
@ResponseBody
Book bookInfo2() {
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setBookName("Ramcharitmanas");
    book.setWriter("TulasiDas");
    return book;
}

@RequestMapping(value ="/book3", produces =MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
public ResponseEntity<Book> bookInfo3() {
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setBookName("Ramayan");
    book.setWriter("Valmiki");
    return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(book);
}
```

For more detail refer to this: 
http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-mvc-jsonp-example-with-rest-responsebody-responseentity

Answer (score 6):

You can use a map with your object or string like bellow :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path", 
        method = RequestMethod.GET, 
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String,String>> getData(){

    Map<String,String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();

    boolean isValid = // some logic
    if (isValid){
        response.put("ok", "success saving data");
        return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(response);
    }
    else{
        response.put("error", "an error expected on processing file");
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(response);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way that I would do it:

```
public ResponseEntity < ? extends BaseResponse > message(@PathVariable String player) { //REST Endpoint.

 try {
  Integer.parseInt(player);
  return new ResponseEntity < ErrorResponse > (new ErrorResponse("111", "player is not found"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
 } catch (Exception e) {


 }
 Message msg = new Message(player, "Hello " + player);
 return new ResponseEntity < Message > (msg, HttpStatus.OK);

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getAll/{player}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity < List < ? extends BaseResponse >> messageAll(@PathVariable String player) { //REST Endpoint.

 try {
  Integer.parseInt(player);
  List < ErrorResponse > errs = new ArrayList < ErrorResponse > ();
  errs.add(new ErrorResponse("111", "player is not found"));
  return new ResponseEntity < List < ? extends BaseResponse >> (errs, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
 } catch (Exception e) {


 }
 Message msg = new Message(player, "Hello " + player);
 List < Message > msgList = new ArrayList < Message > ();
 msgList.add(msg);
 return new ResponseEntity < List < ? extends BaseResponse >> (msgList, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 5):

You can also  implement like this to return Success and Error on a same request mapping method,use Object class(Parent class of every class in java) :-

```
public ResponseEntity< Object> method() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    boolean b = //  logic  here   
      if (b)  
        return new ResponseEntity< Object>(HttpStatus.OK);      
    else      
        return new ResponseEntity< Object>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT); //appropriate error code   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Its possible to return `ResponseEntity` without using generics, such as follows,

```
public ResponseEntity method() {
    boolean isValid = // some logic
    if (isValid){
        return new ResponseEntity(new Success(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    else{
        return new ResponseEntity(new Error(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not specifying generic type would cause `GsonHttpMessageConverter` to complain and throw error. But simply modifying to `ResponseEntity<?>` would make it work.

Comment: Yes.. anyway when using Jackson, its okay to use without generics.

Comment: It will be flagged by most code inspection tools though. So, you would have to add an exception or suppress them for this specific response type. - Not a big fan.

Answer (score 3):

Using custom exception class you can return different HTTP status code and dto objects.

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public ResponseEntity<UserDto> saveUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
    if(userDto.getId() != null) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException("A new user cannot already have an ID");
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.saveUser(userDto));
}
```

Exception class

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "user not found")
public class UserNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public UserNotFoundException(String message) {

        super(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As for spring boot 3.x, my preferred syntax is returning `ResponseEntity<?>` (with generics) - choosing the `HttpStatus` and `body` according to the result/exception; very clean, easy to maintain and agnostic to the type of API/method I use.

E.g.

In this example, I'm returning either a `User` dto or an `INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` with the relevant error message:

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
public ResponseEntity<?> signup(@RequestBody User user) {
    try {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(userService.addUser(user));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: ? will give a sonar error.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use a class like this. The **statusCode** is set when there is an error with the error message set in **message**. Data is stored either in the Map or in a List as and when appropriate.

```
/**
* 
*/
package com.test.presentation.response;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * A simple POJO to send JSON response to ajax requests. This POJO enables  us to
 * send messages and error codes with the actual objects in the application.
 * 
 * 
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class GenericResponse {

/**
 * An array that contains the actual objects
 */
private Collection rows;

/**
 * An Map that contains the actual objects
 */
private Map mapData;

/**
 * A String containing error code. Set to 1 if there is an error
 */
private int statusCode = 0;

/**
 * A String containing error message.
 */
private String message;

/**
 * An array that contains the actual objects
 * 
 * @return the rows
 */
public Collection getRows() {
    return rows;
}

/**
 * An array that contains the actual objects
 * 
 * @param rows
 *            the rows to set
 */
public void setRows(Collection rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
}

/**
 * An Map that contains the actual objects
 * 
 * @return the mapData
 */
public Map getMapData() {
    return mapData;
}

/**
 * An Map that contains the actual objects
 * 
 * @param mapData
 *            the mapData to set
 */
public void setMapData(Map mapData) {
    this.mapData = mapData;
}

/**
 * A String containing error code.
 * 
 * @return the errorCode
 */
public int getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}

/**
 * A String containing error code.
 * 
 * @param errorCode
 *            the errorCode to set
 */
public void setStatusCode(int errorCode) {
    this.statusCode = errorCode;
}

/**
 * A String containing error message.
 * 
 * @return the errorMessage
 */
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

/**
 * A String containing error message.
 * 
 * @param errorMessage
 *            the errorMessage to set
 */
public void setMessage(String errorMessage) {
    this.message = errorMessage;
}
```

}

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Note: if you upgrade from spring boot 1 to spring boot 2 there is a `ResponseStatusException` which has a Http error code and a description.

So, you can effectively use generics they way it is intended.

The only case which is a bit challenging for me, is the response type for a status 204 (ok with no body). I tend to mark those methods as `ResponseEntity<?>`, because `ResponseEntity<Void>` is less predictive.

Answer (score 0):

For exceptional cases, I will recommend you to adopt [RFC-7807 Problem Details for HTTP APIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807)
 standard in your application.

[Zalando's Problems for Spring](https://github.com/zalando/problem-spring-web) provides a good integration with Spring Boot, you can integrate it easily with your existing Spring Boot based application. Just like what [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/managing-server-errors/#api-errors) did.

After adopting RFC-7087 in your application, just throw Exception in your controller method, and you will get a detailed and standard error response like:

```json
   {
    "type": "https://example.com/probs/validation-error",
    "title": "Request parameter is malformed.",
    "status": 400
    "detail": "Validation error, value of xxx should be a positive number.",
    "instance": "/account/12345/msgs/abc",
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow up the answer of **@MarkNorman**, I would say you have to define the mapping between the exceptions coming from your `service` to your `controller` (HTTP Error Code).

- Success response are mapped to `200` status (OK)
- Validation exception mapped with `400` status (BAD_REQUEST)
- Record not found mapped with `404` status (NOT_FOUND)
- Other exception mapped to `500` status (INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

For example, your code should look something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/persons/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Success> findPersonById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    try {
        var person = service.findById(id);
        var message = new Message(HttpStatus.OK, getCurrentDateTime(), person);
        return message;
    } catch(ServiceException exception) {
        throw new NotFoundException("An error occurs while finding a person", exception);
    }
}
```

All the exceptions thrown should be redirect in the `ControllerAdvice`

```
@ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Error> handleNotFoundException(NotFoundException exception) {
    var error = new Error(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                getCurrentDateTime(),
                exception.getMessage());

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(error);
}
```

The main thing to understand is that your `RestControllers` only understand HTTP protocol and HTTP Code for responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ExceptionHandler Controller Advice to return custom Return Object in case error.
See the example code below which returns 400 with Custom response in case of Validation Error.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = InputValidationError.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ValidationErrorResponse> handleException(InputValidationError ex){
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(ex.validationErrorResponse);
    }
}
```