# How to return http response in Spring

Tags: spring, http

I want to replace the http exception with a response, that is, I use responseentity I want to return for example 409 if the user is not found by name, and 509 if not found by mail, can I determine the error number and its description in responseEntity? If so, can  give an example?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/change", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void change(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    User userByUsername = userService.findUserByUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
    if (userByUsername == null) {
        throw new Exception("Пользователь не найден");
        //TODO: return ResponseEntity code 409 if userByusername not found
    }

    user.setId(userByUsername.getId());
    if (user.getPassword() == null) {
        user.setPassword(userByUsername.getPassword());
    }
    user.setRoles(userByUsername.getRoles());
    userService.save(user);
}
```

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117717/what-is-the-best-way-to-return-different-types-of-responseentity-in-spring-mvc-o, discussing the same requirement

Comment: not clear where the ErrorResponse class comes from

Answer (score -1):

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> change(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, "not found user by username",409);
    User userByUsername = userService.findUserByUsername(userDetails.getUsername());
    if (userByUsername == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, new HttpHeaders(), errorResponse.getStatus());
    }
    user.setId(userByUsername.getId());
    if (user.getPassword() == null) {
        user.setPassword(userByUsername.getPassword());
    }
    user.setRoles(userByUsername.getRoles());
    userService.save(user);
    return null;
}

public class ErrorResponse {

private HttpStatus status;
private String message;
private Integer errors;

public ErrorResponse(HttpStatus status, String message, Integer errors) {
    super();
    this.status = status;
    this.message = message;
    this.errors = errors;
}

public HttpStatus getStatus() {
    return status;
}
```

}