# Spring boot REST, handling business logic in the Service or Controller layer?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a `Cake` resource.

My Spring Boot @RestController exposes a GET endpoint that takes a String PathVariable, `cakeName`.

On receiving a request, my expected server behaviour is:

-Checking if this `cakeName` already exists in my database table. If it exists, response with status 200, and response body is in the shape of `{  "success" "true", "result": { "name": "chocolate", "calories": 123 }}`. If it doesn't exist, response with status 200, return a json in the shape `{ "success": "false", "message": "null" }`

The problem is I need my 1 service method to return 2 potential different shape of JSON.

1. For best practice in current year, Should the Service or controller layer handle the checking of existing string in DB and other business logic?
2. How to handle 1 service method returning 2 differently shaped JSON bodies?

I have tried the following, but I am trying to avoid raising errors in my http response.

[What is the best way to return different types of ResponseEntity in Spring-Boot (Error Handling for REST with Spring)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38117717/what-is-the-best-way-to-return-different-types-of-responseentity-in-spring-boot)

Comment: I would say that best practise is to not rewritten different json structures from the same endpoint, because it makes it nearly impossible to write a client. Instead you should use 404 if not found. And skip the success parameter, that is what http status codes are for.

Comment: @AndreasLundgren I disagree. Having a generic wrapper with some always-relevant response fields, and a different-per-endpoint response field, and an error field, is perfectly fine. In fact, it's exactly what the StackExchange API does. The only thing I'd do differently from what's described in the question, is you should still return the right status code. So no 200 OK for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is basically a wrapper object for all API responses, be they error or success. Imagine a structure like this:

```
class ApiResponse<T> {
  boolean success;
  T result;
  ErrorDetails error;
}
```

Now you can simply return an `ApiResponse<T>` from every endpoint, where `T` is the success result type. If the response is an error, set `error=true` and fill in the error details. Leave the `result` field `null`. And the other way around for success responses. You can even configure your JSON serializer to omit `null` fields, which will result in exactly the JSON suggested in the question.

Even when you use this, I'd still recommend using the right HTTP status codes. So a 200-range code for responses with `success=true` and a 400 or 500 range code for responses with `success=false`.

Note that the [StackExchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper)  has a very similar structure.